# Interpreting the ratio test for $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

We want to find the limit of this.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k} $$

I would have done it as follows:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg| = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2+n}}{\frac{n}{n^2+n}} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2+n} \cdot \frac{n^2+n}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3+2n^2+n}{n^3+3n^2+n} \\
=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^3 \cdot \bigl(1+\frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} \bigr)}{n^3\cdot\big(1+\frac{3}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} \bigr)} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$$

According to the ratio test, the series converges if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg| <1$ and it diverges if it's $> 1$.

But since we get  $1$ here, the series converges towards that value, no? But according to the ratio test, we can't make a statement about the series of the limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg| = 1$

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: This isn’t a simple series, so the ratio test doesn’t apply. A simple series is of the form $$\lim_{n\ to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k,$$ but your limit is of the forms $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_{n,k}.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So we can only get the limit via squeeze theorem here? $\frac{n^2}{n^2+n} \leq a_n \leq \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1$?

Comment: Well, “only” is a strong word. But you can’t use directly only using theorems that apply only to a series.

Comment: There is no $a_n.$ There is only $a_{n,k}.$

Comment: But yes, the squeeze theorem is probably the best way, using that $$\frac n{n^2+1}\leq a_{n,k} \leq \frac{n}{n^2+n}$$ for $1\leq k\leq n.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ratio test is used when

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k ~~~~~~~~~~\lim_{k \to \infty} \bigg| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\bigg|$$

But here you have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k(n)$$

Comment: What is my $a_k$ here and what is $(n)$?

Comment: I mean you have index $k$, and $a_k$ depends on $n$, so $a_{k}(n)$ so you can't use ratio test.

Answer (score 1):

Will you allow me a proof without the ratio test which I think you

didn't use it in the correct way. We are interested in the limit of the

sum $s_{n}=n[\dfrac{1}{n^{2}+1}+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}+2}+....+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}+n}]$.

Notice that $\dfrac{1}{n^{2}+1}<\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}$ and likewise .... till

$\dfrac{1}{n^{2}+n}<\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}$. Hence the sum in brackets is less or equal to:

$\dfrac{n}{n^{2}}$=$\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Therefore $s_{n}\leq n\dfrac{1}{n}=1$. Also the sum in brackets is $\geq$ than $\dfrac{n}{n^{2}+n}$, which is $\dfrac{1}{n+1}$. Multiplied by $n$  we get $s_{n}\geq\,\dfrac{n}{n+1}$.Thus the sequence $s_{n}$ is such that $\dfrac{n}{n+1}\,\leq\,s_{n}\leq\,1$ and certainly converges to $1$!! Therefore the series converges to $1$.!!

Comment: The series converge? Which series? The problem ask for a limit that is NOT a series, otherwise the ratio test could be applied. (See the other answers)

Comment: The limit of sums depending on n is an infinite series! A series is the limit of finite sums! When the finite sums are bounded by1 the series converges! Read the question and my proof carefully!

Comment: Yes, a series is a limit of finite sums: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$, but that is not the case, because the summands depends not only on $k$, but also on $n$.

Comment: I'm willing to discuss with actual arguments, you're welcome to do the same instead of trying to make fun of me.

Comment: My friend this is a crystal clear proof of the result which agrees with another answer (which uses more complicated approach). Don't think of whether is series or not! We are asked to find the limit of $s_{n}$ and  I proved with elementary arguments that it is ${1}$. There is not much to discuss here!

Comment: So you agree that is not a series?

Comment: Also, I downvoted the answer **before** you edited the answer because your old answer used to say that $s_n$ been bounded was enough to prove convergence, which is false.

Comment: It was enough to prove that the sums do NOT diverge! But the new edit calculates the exact limit. So I would expect an upvote now!

Comment: Proving a sequence is bounded is not enough to show that the sequence not diverge. Even if that were true, your answer used to affirm *convergence*: "Therefore $s_n \le n\frac{1}{n}=1$. Thus the series converges!!"

Comment: As written now the answer is an actual proof that the **sequence** converges to $1$. Lifting the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with harmonic numbers
$$a_n= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k}=n \left(H_{n^2+n}-H_{n^2}\right)$$

Using the asymptotics
$$H_p=\log (p)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ and continuing with Taylor series
$$a_n=1-\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{6 n^2}+\frac{1}{4
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Use it for $n=10$ : the exact result is
$$a_{10}=\frac{11210403701434961}{11818204429243212}=0.948571$$ while the truncated series gives
$$\frac{11383}{12000}=0.948583$$

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Ratio Test doesn't work for that kind of sum you have.

Recall for $n > 1$ and any decreasing function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that

$$\int_{1}^{n+1}f(x)dx \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k) \leq \int_{0}^{n}f(x)dx.$$

Let $f(x) = \frac{n}{n^2+x}.$ Then after some integrating, we get

$$\int_1^{n+1}f(x)dx = n\ln{\left(1+\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right)}$$

and

$$\int_0^nf(x)dx = n\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}.$$

Take the limit as $n$ goes to infinity and apply the Squeeze Theorem. I think you can take it from there. Your final answer should be $1$.